# Formatting Highcharts - timestamp in tooltip, day x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, data-visualization, date-formatting

My chart is updated every second and I'd like to show timestamp (i.e. April 7, 2016, 15:12:38) in tooltip and day on x axis. It should look like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/qq5rqazj/2/ . I dont know how to customize my chart. I enclose snippet of code:

```
       $('#container').highcharts({
            chart:{
                    type: 'spline',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg,
                    marginRight: 10,
                    events: {load: function () {series = this.series[0];}}
                },
            title:{text: 'Live random data'},
            xAxis:{tickPixelInterval: 150},
            yAxis:{title: {text: 'Value'},
                plotLines: [{value: 0,width: 1,color: '#808080'}]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.x, 2) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                    }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{ name: 'Random data', data:DatosRecuperados}]
        });
```

x, y are values from database where x is int and y is current time stamp 2016-05-29 17:56:15

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `Highcharts.dateFormat()` method in your toolip (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat).

The example below will return for format `May 30, 2016` for `this.x`:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x) + '<br/>' + 
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
    }
},
```

As noted in Highcharts documentation:

> Formats a JavaScript date timestamp (milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970)
>   into a human readable date string. The format is a subset of the
>   formats for PHP's strftime function.

This is only a subset, as it won't accept certain values such as `%c` for a complete timestamp.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use builtin [xDateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.xDateFormat) option.

```
tooltip: {
    xDateFormat: '%B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S',
},
```

You can see the demo on [this Highcharts' fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/xdateformat/).